# How to Copy/Paste text box from MS Word to Powerpoint slide?

Tags: vba, ms-word, powerpoint, powerpoint-2010

I am currently creating a document that will take the format and text from a MS Word document and paste it into a text box in a PowerPoint template. I have looked all over to see how this can be done and haven't found much. Any help would be much appreciated!!

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim pptApp As Object
Dim pptPres As String
Dim folderPath, file As String

    folderPath = ActiveDocument.Path & Application.PathSeparator
    file = "Huntington_Template.pptx"
    pptApp.Visible = True
    pptApp.presentations.Open (folderPath & file)

    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Update_Image").Range.Copy 'text box to copy in MS WS
    'not sure what to do next?

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice a few errors in your code:

- You haven't created an instance of PowerPoint.Application
- You have declared `pptPres` as String but probably should be `As Object` to represent a Powerpoint.Presentation object
- You do not make any assignment to `pptPres`

This would be easier to do by the Shape's `.Name` but I think this will work.  I have made some other changes to declare some more variables in addition to those above.

```
Sub Test()
Dim pptApp As Object    'PowerPoint.Application
Dim pptPres As Object   'PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim folderPath As String, file As String
Dim bk As Bookmark
Dim doc As Document
Dim wdRange As Range
Dim shpTextBox as Object 'PowerPoint.Shape

    '## As a matter of prefernce I use variable rather than "ActiveDocument"
    Set doc = ActiveDocument

    '## Use a variable for the bookmark
    Set bk = doc.Bookmarks("Update_Image")

    '## Assign to the pptApp Application Object
    Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

    folderPath = doc.Path & Application.PathSeparator
    file = "Huntington_Template.pptx"

    pptApp.Visible = True
    '## assign to the pptPres Presentation Object
    Set pptPres = pptApp.presentations.Open(folderPath & file)

    '## Select the bookmark so we can copy it
    bk.Select

    '## Copy it
    Selection.Copy


    'Note: ensure you are at the correct slide location

    '## Assign to the shpTextBox & select it:
    Set shpTextBox = pptPres.Slides(1).Shapes("Text Box 2")
    shpTextBox.Select

    '## Paste in to PPT
    pptApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteSourceFormatting"


End Sub
```

**NOTE** This pastes directly to the slide, if you need to put it in a specific textbox/shape in the PowerPoint slide, let me know. I am fairly certain that could be done by specifying the shape name in PowerPoint/etc.

I've seen the `CommandBars.ExecuteMso` method before but it is not very well-documented compared to many other methods. The `Application.CommandBars` [property reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744604%28v=office.14%29.aspx) has nary a mention of the `ExecuteMso` method, which I found some information about here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862419(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862419%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

> This method is useful in cases where there is no object model for a particular command. Works on controls that are built-in buttons, toggleButtons and splitButtons.

You'll need a list of *idMso* parameters to explore, which come as part of a rather large downloadable file, current for Office 2013 I believe:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=727

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you! I am trying to paste the contents directly into a textbox on the slide versus directly to the slide. Can you help with this as well?

I did add the PowerPoint 14.0 reference library so I now have access to those methods.

Comment: When naming a shape/textbox in PowerPoint, is that done through the Selection Pane in the Formatting tab?

Comment: Yes, I was just about to mention that. If you don't know the name, use the Selection pane to see the name (and edit it if needed).

Comment: BTW, updated my answer above to paste to specific shape in PowerPoint :)

Comment: Do let me know if this works for you, and if so, please consider accepting the answer so that others with similar Q's in the future may benefit from this.

Comment: David that works awesome! I'll have to do some manipulation to customize things but this is awesome! Thank you! How do I accept the answer?