# VBA Script to Copy Excel Chart to Word not working in later versions of Word

Tags: excel, vba, charts, ms-word, copy-paste

I am trying to copy an Excel Chart to Word.  I have the following script in Excel and it works with Office 2003 for PC and Office Mac 2011. In a later version of Office (2016) the chart does not resize when pasted and the token it searches for does not get replaced with the chart as it does in the earlier versions.  Here is the script that works but not on later versions of Office.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
Set wrd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrd.Documents(DocumentName).Activate
        wrd.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        With wrd.Selection.Find
            .Text = "insert" & ChartName 'This is the token it is looking for in the Word document and is where the chart should be inserted. 
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = 1 'wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .Execute
            If .Found = True Then
                wrd.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=13  'wdChartPicture
            End If
```

In the earlier versions of Office this script takes the active chart copies it and pastes it into Word by looking for the token and pasting it.  The token is replaced by the chart and the chart is resized.  In the newer versions the token remains at the bottom of the chart and the chart is not resized.

If it is not possible to figure out why it doesn't work, is it possible to write the code in a way that forces it to work in all versions of Office? I tried to make sure all preferences are the same but could I have missed some preference that could be causing the problem.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated because this is quite an issue for me.

Comment: When you step through this code, is the `.Found = True` condition met?

Comment: If so, I would look at the `ExecuteMSO` method ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35605460/copy-text-formatting-in-a-excel-to-word-script/35606101#35606101) is a similar question copying range of cells from Excel to Word) and here are [a few more](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1467082+ExecuteMso) mostly from Excel to PowerPoint, but the general idea is the same, you just need to identify which verb to call, and that should be the most reliable.

Comment: The .found condition is indeed true.  I tried replacing the line wrd.selection.pasteandformat Type:=13  with wrd.CommandBars.ExecuteMso “PasteasPicture”  and get an error message saying "object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: Note, I am testing this on my Mac with Office 2011.  Once I know my changes work on this version, I will test it on the newer versions.

Comment: I know that should work on Excel 2010+, but I don't know about Mac. I'd be surprised if ExecuteMso doesn't work, then again, it's Mac and they restrict some things in vba unnecessarily...

Comment: The above command does not work on Windows 10 either.  One other piece of information, the new version of Office that the script does not work on is 2016.

Comment: `wrd.Selection.PasteAndFormat` and `wrd.CommandBars.ExecuteMso` both work in Excel 2010, but unfortunately I don't have 2016 to test on (I could test on 2013 but not sure if that would be helpful).  What do you mean by "does not work" -- do you get an error? If so, what's the error and what statement is trying to execute which raises the error?

Comment: You may also want to try `.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have basically two questions:

1. Why doesn't this work in Excel 2016
2. How can I make this code version-independent and OS-independent?

I don't have 2016 Excel, nor Mac OS, so I may not be able to answer #1, but I will share some of my findings in Excel 2010 and 2013 in case that may help you find the solution in 2016. I am able to answer #2, below.

## Excel 2010/2013 Findings:

In 2010 Excel, I was able to see some similar issues, the `.Execute` was not actually replacing the text. What I observe is that `.Execute` was changing the *selection* -- essentially the `.Execute` *selects* the found text. IOW, it doesn't default to *replace*, it just *finds* and *selects*.  In order to *replace*, I needed to do:

```
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

However, both paste (whether `PasteAndFormat` or `ExecuteMso` were successfully replacing the new "selection".

**I observe the same in Excel 2013**, [which is the latest version documented on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193977(v=office.14).aspx) and presumably same object model as 2016.

**NB** I used the `.CopyPicture` method instead of the `.Copy` method. You may have better luck with that method. It's worth a shot.

## The quest for version-independent (and OS-independent code)

> is it possible to write the code in a way that forces it to work in all versions of Office?

Yes, and this would require identifying what works in each version, and using a technique called [Conditional Compilation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240847(v=vs.60).aspx). Typically this technique is used to accommodate changes in the object model which would raise a compile error.

For example, let's say *this* block of code works in 2003:

```
        .Execute
        If .Found = True Then
            wrd.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=13  'wdChartPicture
        End If
```

And this block of code works in 2010 and 2013:

```
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        If .Found = True Then
            wrd.CommandBars.ExecuteMSO "PasteAsPicture"
        End If
```

And some other code works in 2016+ (this is not real code, but bear with me):

```
       .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
       If .Found = True Then
           wrd.SOMETHING_FOR_2016
       End If
```

Then you would do:

```
#If Mac Then
    Debug.Print "Mac"
    .Execute
    If .Found = True Then
        wrd.SOMETHINGFORMAC 'pseudo-code
    End If
#Else
    Debug.Print "Windows"
    Select Case CLng(Application.Version)
        Case 11 'Excel 2003
            Debug.Print 2003
            .Execute
            If .Found = True Then
                wrd.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=13  'wdChartPicture
            End If
        Case 14 'Excel 2010
            Debug.Print 2010
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            If .Found = True Then
                wrd.CommandBars.ExecuteMSO "PasteAsPicture"
            End If
        Case 15 'Excel 2013
            Debug.Print 2013
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            If .Found = True Then
                wrd.CommandBars.ExecuteMSO "PasteAsPicture"
            End If
        Case Is > 15 'Excel 2016+
            Debug.Print "2016+"
           .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
           If .Found = True Then
               wrd.SOMETHING_FOR_2016
           End If
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Other versions would require add'l logic..."
    End Select
#End If
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I will try this but I won't be able to do so until the end of next week.  I will let you know what happens.

Comment: In the mean time I did try it on the Mac.  I replaced the lines 
        If .Found = True Then
            wrd.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=13  'wdChartPicture
        End If  
with the following
        If .Found = True Then
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End If   
The code executed but nothing happened, i.e., the text did not get replaced with the chart.  I am not a professional programmer so maybe I misunderstood the instructions.

Comment: I also tried the copypicture method but it said it didn't exist.  The script is in an Excel file trying to copy the selected chart.  It has no problem with the copy method.

Comment: the `.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll` won't replace the text with the chart, it should replace with the `.Replacement.Text` (i.e., `""`), and you'd need another command to paste the chart.

Comment: For `CopyPicture`, do `ActiveChart.CopyPicture` instead of `ActiveChart.ChartArea.CopyPicture`

Comment: Thanks so much.  It now works the way it has always worked on my Mac.  I will try this in Office 2016 next week and see if it fixes the problem.  I have my fingers crossed.

Comment: It worked beautifully on Office 2016.  Thanks so much for your help.  So I understand, is there an explanation for why .CopyPicture worked (i.e., resized properly) but .ChartArea.Copy did not?

Comment: I think that [CopyPicture is a method of the Chart object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841052.aspx), not a method of the [ChartArea](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834478.aspx)

Comment: Also, do consider accepting the answer if it's been helpful for you.  Cheers.

Comment: Forgive me but this is the first time I have used the forum.  I would love to accept the answer but am not exactly sure what that means.  I hit the up arrow on the answer but I am too new for it to actually increment the counter.  Should I be doing something else?

Comment: It's not the up arrow, I think between the up and down arrows there's a check mark could you can select